# Что за время жизни AddInstance в DI?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

В официальной [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/june/essential-net-dependency-injection-with-net-core) майкрософт пишется, что существует 4 времени жизни для объектов, при их добавлении в `IServiceColletion`. Кроме общеизвестных `Single`, `Scoped`, `Transient` упоминается еще `Instance`. Однако помимо этой статьи, я не смог найти упоминания или нормального объяснения того, что такое `AddInstance`, более того, я не могу вызвать этот метод у `ServiceCollection`.

Comment: Вы бы ссылку привели...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/june/essential-net-dependency-injection-with-net-core

Comment: А, это ж не официальная документация, а статья в журнале. Её как выпустили, так и не исправляли с 2016 года, зачем вы вообще её читали?

Comment: Доверился недостоверному источнику) спасибо))